# A trivial code that builds cleanly with msbuild 14/VS 2015, but fails to compile in msbuild 15/VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class MyAttribute1 : Attribute
    {
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class MyAttribute2 : Attribute
    {
    }

    [MyAttribute1 MyAttribute2]
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Notice there is no comma between the attributes applied to Program. I was profoundly surprised to discover it compiles with msbuild 14/VS 2015, but fails to compile with msbuild 15/VS 2017.

My expectation was to see it failing in both versions.

Can anyone explain what is going on?

**EDIT 1**

Here is how the reflected code appears in Reflector:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reflection to see if both attributes were actually applied?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the fact that it was able to compile in msbuild14 is a bug.

The C# v5 language [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) (page 394) states:

> Attributes are specified in  attribute sections . An attribute section
>   consists of a pair of square brackets, which  surround a comma
>   - separated list of one or more attributes. The order in which attributes are specified in such  a list, and the order in which
>   sections attached to the same program entity are arranged, is not
>   significant. **For  instance, the attribute specifications  [A][B] , 
>   [B][A] ,  [A, B] , and  [B, A] are equivalent.**

The formal syntax is:

[image]

The syntax you posted, `[MyAttribute1 MyAttribute2]` , is not accounted for.

So, I assume that it was a bug that it was able to compile, and they fixed it in msbuild 15.

Comment: Good for them. Now we have regressions.

Comment: @mark Actually, failure to compile is a bugfix rather than a regression :D. No idea is earlier versions of Visual Studio compiled the flawed code or not, but considering the whole compiler was rewritten from scratch, no doubt there could be many regressions there.

Comment: @mark Not 100% sure, but it might be possible to configure your projects to build using a specific version of msbuild - you might want to look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-toolset-toolsversion?view=vs-2017

Comment: @DanLing - I do not think we want to get stuck with an old msbuild. We will just fix the code.